# Find percentile-scores from non-normal (cumulative) density curves

Tags: r, ggplot2, percentile, density-plot

I have a dataset with one variable and some observations (let's say n = 50) for which I have drawn a density curve with ggplot2. Since my raw scores don't follow a normal distribution and do not exist of (depict) all possible scores on the given scale. I would like to use the smoothed density curve to calculate all new (or missing) "raw scores" for some set of percentiles. Is this possible, maybe with or am I not thinking straight and making things to difficult? I included an example based on carat variable from the diamonds dataset. In this cases the raw scores range from 0 to 2 and I would like to find all (fictive) raw scores connected to the 5th, 10th ... 90th and the 95th percentile. Hope someone can help me out and give me some directions (in order to make a norm-table for diagnostic use).

```
library(tidyverse)

seed(42)

data(diamonds) 
df <- diamonds %>% 
      filter(cut == "Ideal") %>%  # creating smaller dataset
      select(carat) %>% 
      sample_n(size = 50, replace = FALSE)

ggplot(df, aes(carat)) +
  geom_density(adjust = 1)
```

Comment: Do you maybe just need to use the quantile function?

Comment: Could be very well, but will the quantile function return the same values as let's say the value on the x-axis for which the area to the left under the curve is 5 percent for the 5th quantile?. The density curve you can adjust for smoothness, so then the area changes a bit, doesn't it?

Comment: i'm looking for something that does the inverse of integrating based on the curve drawn by ggplot, i think.

Comment: You mean quantile regression with intercept only and use predicted scores?

Comment: The functions quantile() and quantileCI() don't solve my problem, they don't intra-polate non existing percentiles in my data.